# Referencing the right information in a continuous form

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a button at the end of each record on a continuous form and it needs to do this:

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Dim SellP As Double
Dim BuyP As Double
Dim Profit As Double

SellP = DLookup(SellPrice, Flips, [Current])
BuyP = DLookup(BuyPrice, Flips, [Current])

Profit = SellP - BuyP

Flips.Profit = Profit

End Sub
```

Now I know this isn't the correct code but I hope it will give you an idea of what it needs to do, essentially:

Find the SalePrice, find the BuyPrice, minus the BuyPrice from the SalePrice and make the result Profit, then populate the Profit field with profit..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of the current record of the bound table/query are directly available in the code.
You can just write e.g.
`Profit = SalePrice - BuyPrice` if these fields are all part of the bound data.
You might then move this code in the "AfterUpdate"-Event of both the SalePrice- and the BuyPrice-Textfields, maybe like this:

```
If IsNull(salePrice) Or IsNull(buyPrice) Then
    Profit = 0
Else
    Profit = salePrice - buyPrice
End If
```

Comment: How do I then input that data into the datasheet? After I have established what profit actually is.

Comment: I was thinking your continuous form has textboxes bound to those fields, which serve for entering the data. The form should be used for the data input, not the data sheet directly.